# xrdp Requiring Numeric IP Address from Windows

Tags: raspbian-stretch, xrdp

I have xrdp installed and running on a Raspberry Pi 3B+ running stretch. The Pi's name and address, from the /etc/hosts file, are:

```
10.0.0.5    mycroft
```

When I try to access the Pi from Windows 10 via Remote Desktop Connection, if I specify "mycroft" as the target the connection fails -- I get asked for a user name & password, but they're rejected -- while if I specify the numeric IP address RDC launches & I immediately get the xrdp signin screen.

Doing `nslookup mycroft` on the Windows command line shows the name correctly resolving to 10.0.0.5

I've never seen a situation where a numeric IP address works but its human-readable alternative fails.

Thoughts on what's going on, and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Sigh. Turns out the problem was that my hosts file contained two entries for the Pi:

```
127.0.1.1      mycroft
10.0.0.5        mycroft
```

When accessing the Pi by name, Remote Desktop defaulted to using the first entry, which of course failed, since it referred to the Windows machine's loopback address.

Removing the first entry from /etc/hosts solved the problem.